# Errors while using the drawer and then coping classes and linking file resources

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-wear-2.0

I wanted to create an Android app for my Sony Smartwatch 3 and barely know anything about Android Studio and how to cope with the different files to get things working.

That's why I started with an Android Developers Guide (a difficult and not at all precise one ("creating and running a wearable app")) .

As you might guess, this Android Wear device I have does not support the current API so I could not fully implement the code depicted in the guide and had to tweak the APIs and dependencies which was a hell of a work for a nonprofessional like me. I seemed to have gotten that working and I could actually get the app with a custom text displayed on my watch.

**The current situation:**
Then there was the next step I wanted to go, implement a drawer so I can enter a new menu when swiping up or so. Therefore I had a look at "Navigation and Actions with Wear 2.0", a tutorial that is much more suitable for beginners but based on a project they provide which is for round smartwatches, so I could not easily use that and had to stick to the more elaborated [support page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions) on Android Developers regarding the drawer.

**Problem 1:** (I hope) I implemented the drawer code like it said there and now I get a compiler error of a failed linking file resource but I don't know why. I can't find any clue in the `acitvity_main.xml` where users with similar answers on StackOverflow pointed to.

**Problem 2:** Plus, there is this problem with the navigation drawer adapter which was linked to a class I implemented like on the Developer support page which then led to a not instantiatable class in `MainActivity.java`.

I'm sorry for so much text to read and so less examples off the errors!
I think it gets clearer having a look at the files. I uploaded the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQgOjCSVJCCpwczIt4mhqk5d1C2GgmQ9/view?usp=sharing) and hope you can tell me anything I can do to make it work.

I have actually no idea how to move on in the project, I think I could not have started off any easier with this goal to create a Wear app and hope anybody has the nerves to give me a hint.

Screenshot of the errors:
[image]

Logcat:

> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   ...
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A
>   problem occurred configuring project ':app'.  at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)

...

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem
>   occurred configuring project ':app'.  at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)

...

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find Build Tools
>   revision 27.0.3   at
>   com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:176)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:885)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:702)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw. yes, I tried to clean and rebuild the project as well as closing and reimporting it :) in this case it did not help though (previously it did once)

Comment: Did you just copy pasted the code or you wrote yourself

Comment: We need to see the logcat to be able to help you. Show us those errors you are getting

Comment: Alright, sure. Does this log help? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EYTQRwL-iT6HAGPNezLiNc-ej_HS73SW

The code is rather copy paste and then trying to fix the errors :/

Comment: That's the display of all errors in the build window: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KWInPhdGXWXSAFyPg3o47P9gimxiBZX8

Comment: It seems like you don't have `Build Tools revision 27.0.3` installed on your computer! Can you show us your Build gradle file? The one with `(:app)`

Comment: Alright, I hope, that's the one you want to see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XkiKJ2XDmms42inRxZAPcei9ZICRWp38
I thought I had eliminated the errors due to dependencies though.

Btw.: I had the project running at work today to be able to reply to you before the evening. Maybe the failure mode could be a bit different at home (will have you updated for that later today).

Comment: I get your project building, it has several  errors that I'm trying to address in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project has several errors! On the MainActivity.java, you have a duplicate of the onCreate() method:

[image]

- Install Build tool or use version 28 instead
- `mWearableNavigationDrawer = findViewById(R.id.to_navigation_drawer)`; cannot be resolved because you don't have a layout with that ID! Instead you have `top_drawer` (I guess) as the ID of your WearableNavigationDrawer
- `mWearableNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(YourImplementationnavigationAdapter);` also throw an error, you need an expression here which is your adapter. Something like:  `mWearableNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(new YourImplementationNavigationAdapter(this));`

As YourImplementationNavigationAdapter is abstract, you need to implement its methods like below:

```
mWearableNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(new YourImplementationNavigationAdapter(this){ 
     @Override
        public CharSequence getItemText(int i) {
            return null;
        }

            @Override
            public Drawable getItemDrawable(int i) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

- In `activity_main.xml`, you should comment out/remove this line :  `app:actionMenu="@menu/action_drawer_menu` this reference an item in menu folder which isn't present in the resource folder. Or you should create it.
- The same as above goes for the activity_main_backup.xml

Correcting these, your project should build now. Simply click on rebuild project.

**UPDATE:**

Your `MainActivity.java` should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

private WearableDrawerLayout mWearableDrawerLayout;
private WearableNavigationDrawerView mWearableNavigationDrawer;
private WearableActionDrawerView mWearableActionDrawer;


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Top navigation drawer
    mWearableNavigationDrawer = (WearableNavigationDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.top_drawer);
    mWearableNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(new YourImplementationNavigationAdapter(this) {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getItemText(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getItemDrawable(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    // Peeks navigation drawer on the top.
    mWearableNavigationDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();
    // Bottom action drawer
    mWearableActionDrawer = (WearableActionDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_action_drawer);
    // Peeks action drawer on the bottom.
    mWearableActionDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();
    mWearableActionDrawer.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

}
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for your efforts!  

I began to make the changes but might have to check for Build version at home again (something that is not inside the code).    
Here at work I had the Android SDK Build Tools of Revision 27.0.3 already installed but reinstalled it now

Comment: I really did not see the duplication of onCreate and have merged them now

Comment: `top_drawer` is already declared in activity_main.xml. Its the ID of `WearableNavigationDrawerView`

Comment: I see what you mean with the wrong ID I inserted in `findViewById`. The thing is, if I put in `top_drawer` I have to declare that ID somewhere but don't know where (sorry for my low Java skills there).

Comment: Alright, I see that now. But why can't AndroidStudio resolve it to a symbol in MainActivity? Do I need to create it as a local variable again?

Comment: That's is the ID of the layout, it can't be assigned to a variable! You are initializing `mWearableNavigationDrawer`telling android that that object has a layout which has the ID top_drawer

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15nygkz3th__d-9XboTvAWrvpbC_aYnH9
I tried to have an instantiation like you proposed here and like I had before I left it out, which leads to the error of an Abstract class which can't be instantiated

Comment: I'm unfortunately bad at explaining :( I wish I could explain more

Comment: That's why I told you to import its method. Read again, more carefully my answer. >YourImplementationNavigationAdapter

Comment: No problem, you're very helpful and I will understand it once it works (hopefully ;D).
So if I want to initialize `mWearableNavigationDrawer`, what do I need to insert to make it recognize the layout ID `top_drawer` as already declared (in activity_main.xml)? Or should I not name it "top_drawer" in `fieldViewById`?

Comment: I read it but did not understand it completely. I am really trying :)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IjL9TbIec0EGHLIzkRDRUUkU50-IQQZq
You don't mean importing all its methods like this, do you?

Comment: Check my update. I think, you should learn the basics on how to make simple app android app. Remember: learn to walk before trying to run

Comment: top_drawer is set as ID for one of your `WearableNavigationDrawerView` in both  activity_main.xml and activity_main_backup.xml files!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I know. It was just a collision of what might be the better choice (learning to create the easy phone app rather than the Wear app) with what I could actually need. I will get back to the first tutorial if this does not work out or get me into more trouble trying out more Wear app functions :)
comparing your update of mainActivity.java with mine now

Comment: I see what you meant now!
forgot the `R.id.` as I did not know how the reference works.
Was able to push the app to the watch now. Thank you so much! :)